# Where are all the pictures in Professor's Album in Cut the rope: Experiments?

Tags: cut-the-rope-experiments

I just finished all the levels and want to find all the pictures also.
Where are all the pictures in Professor's Album in Cut the rope: Experiments?

Related question: [Where are all the hidden drawings in Cut The Rope?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141965/where-are-all-the-hidden-drawings-in-cut-the-rope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what version is running on android and therefore what levels/photos it has, but the current list of all photos for the iOS version is as follows and should be the same if I'm not mistaken:

1. Like *Cut the Rope* on facebook.
2. Level 1-14: In the upper-left, next to Om Nom.
3. Level 2-19: Above the second star, towards the middle of the level. You need to at least swing on the first suction rope to see it.
4. (iPad Only) Level 3-15: In the upper-right corner, aligned with the upper trampolines.
5. Level 3-19: In the lower right corner. You need to swing past the spikes to see it.
6. Level 4-7: Towards the top of the level on the right side. Down and right of Om Nom, but above the third star. You need to fly towards the top of the level to see it.
7. Level 5:23: On the right side of the drain in the background of the upper right of the level where the second star is. You need to bounce to the last trampoline to see it.
8. Level 6-17: Directly above the star closest to Om Nom in about the upper enter of the screen where the level starts.
9. [Level 8-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eap6.jpg): On the far right of the screen next to Om Nom.

Videos for 1-7 can be found on [this guide](http://www.cuttheropecheats.com/cut-the-rope-drawings/cut-the-rope-experiments-photo-locations/).

A video of 8 can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nd9FjkMjLd0).